# Visual Studio 8.0 for Mac is unable to display/edit .cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I don't know what happened, but my Visual Studio (version 8.1.5) for macOS has become unusable:

- It will simply not display anything when I try to open a `.cs` file.
- The Preferences menu doesn't work (`Visual Studio -> Preferences` doesn't do anything).

It can create projects (like a .NET Core console application), and even build/run them (such as the Hello World sample) - but it cannot edit their files (you can double-click on `Program.cs` and it will open a new tab, but the tab is absolutely empty).

So I decided to have a fresh install.

I deleted the application from `Applications`, and also deleted the `8.0` folder found in `Library/Application Support/Visual Studio` which I presume was related to this installation.

Then I re-downloaded (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) and the installation is successful. But the issues persist.

I have no idea what's going on at this point. I happen to have an old Visual Studio app (7.0) which works fine, but I can't update it to 8.0 from within the app (I think they blocked the update channel for it, so you need to download the 8.0 installer).

What other steps can I try to get Visual Studio 8.0 working on my Mac?

I am running `macOS Mojave 10.14.5`. Visual Studio 8.0 was working fine yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.1.5 on my MacOS 10.15 beta. Some of the .cs files looks empty and some just shows the first several lines. But it is good now after I upgrade the Visual Studio to **8.2**.

Comment: This works indeed. After an update to Catalina, I had that issue with 8.1.*. VS update on Mac failed, so I had to remove it and install VS 8.3.* to fix the issue.

Comment: Im on build 8.5.2 and now experience the issue in April 2020 weird.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what caused the issues, turns out there are far more things to delete if you really want to remove Visual Studio from your macOS machine, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019.

The steps that I followed were:

```
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Visual\ Studio
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin/
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio/7.0/LocalInstall/Addins/
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio/8.0/LocalInstall/Addins/
```

And optionally:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin
```

Then a fresh install fixed the issues. However I cannot tell what caused them to begin with.